# Unable to import module from parent directory in package

Tags: python

I have the following the directory structure

```
pytest_testing/
    __init__.py  
    math_ops.py
    dbs/  
        __init__.py
        dbConnect.py 
    tests/
        test1.py
```

Now in test1.py i am trying to do import a function from dbConnect module, like this `from pytest_testing.dbs.dbConnect import query_data` but i get error "No Module named pytest_testin.

If i try the same in a directory above pytest_testing everything works just fine. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: `No Module named pytest_testin` without G at the end? And to make it work `from ..dbs.dbConnect import query_data`

Comment: That was just a typo.. There is no missing G at end. Also the relative import also doesn't work it says something attempted to import beyond package

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just type this `from dbs.dbConnect import query_data`.
I think this can work well

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux or Windows use the code:

```
# test1.py

import sys
sys.path.append(/path/to/pytest_testing/dbs/)
from dbConnect import functionName #dbConnect without .py extension
```

Comment: This seems to work, but do i always have to append the package path to sys path ???? This is more like a hack than a pythonic solution:)

Comment: By default, Python only searches the current directory (i.e. the dir from where the entry-point script is running) and `sys.path` that includes locations such as package installation directory, thus appending the required package path to the sys path is "non-pythonic" but "one-reliable-way" of doing it.